# Unable to Click Button Using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on a button that's in a frame element. I know I'm selecting the right button because I can print its textContent:

```
let buttonText = await frame.evaluate( button => button.textContent, button );
console.log( buttonText ); // Prints the correct button text.
```

However, if I try clicking the button, nothing happens:

```
button.click();
```

Here is my script:

```
const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );

( async() => {
    var url = 'https://www.example.com';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
        headless: true,
        args: [ '--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process', '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox' ],
    } );

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto( url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 0
    } );

    await page.waitForSelector( 'frame' );
    const frameElement = await page.$( '#FRMSET > frame' );
    const frame = await frameElement.contentFrame();

    await frame.waitForXPath( '/html/body/form/div[7]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]' );
    const [ button ] = await frame.$x( '/html/body/form/div[7]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]' );

    button.click();

    await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 2000 ) ); // Delay 2 seconds.

    await browser.close();

} ) ();
```

The script runs without any errors by button.click() doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably not concerned, but do not forget `await` before `button.click();`.

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(await frameElement.contentFrame())`?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes `elementHandle.click()` does not work due to complicated click emulation algorithm, but the web API variant in evaluated function works. Try this:

```js
    const [ button ] = await frame.$x( '/html/body/form/div[7]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]' );

    await frame.evaluate(element => { element.click(); }, button);

    await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 2000 ) ); // Delay 2 seconds.
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second argument, button?

Comment: It is a way to transfer an elementHandle into the evaluated function as an element. See signature and examples in [`frame.evaluate(pageFunction[, ...args])`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#frameevaluatepagefunction-args).

Comment: Where is element coming from?

Comment: @GTSJoe The `button` is your `const [ button ] = await frame.$x( '/html/body/form/div[7]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]' );`. It becomes the `element` in the evaluated function.

Comment: @GTSJoe I've adjusted the code fragment in the answer to add more context.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but unfortunately, still no success.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I think you should have something like

```
await page.click(button)
```

instead of

```
button.click()
```

Would have commented instead of answered (but I don't have 50 rep yet) hence if it's not the right answer, I'm sorry!

For example, in my code for a similar action, I have:

```
await page.click('.sc-kAzzGY',{delay: 10});
```

Comment: A noble effort, but in my case, I tried: frame.click( button ); and got: Error: JSHandles can be evaluated only in the context they were created.

Comment: Important: The button I'm trying to click is inside a <frame> element.

Comment: It seems it is just a typo, the author of the answer may mean `await frame.click(buttonSelector)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the context to the iframe, and then click to selector.

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v9.0.0&show=api-class-frame

Comment: The button is actually in a <frame> not <iframe>.