# puppteer click() method not working although element is recognized by xPath

Tags: javascript, xpath, automation, click, puppeteer

I'm using the current code section in several tests:

```
const menuIcon = await page.$x(`//span[contains(@class,'icon-menu-wrap')]`);
await menuIcon[0].click();
```

Until now it worked perfectly, but now I got this new test where the login process to the website is a bit different than usual.
Still, I made sure that puppeteer recognizes the element (after using `page.$x` I can see an array containing exactly one item), but the click method won't do anything, but also won't throw any error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526245/2625560

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share the site or a [mcve] of the HTML/JS behavior. A possible solution is `await menuIcon[0].evaluate(el => el.click())` and the idea is to use the native DOM's click function which is much less complex than Puppeteer's, not requiring visibility and mouse contact. But it's all blind guesswork without the site itself; many scenarios are possible.

Comment: The answer by @ggorlen should be marked as the correct answer. This solved the issue for me

Comment: @AndyVennells thanks and I'm glad it worked for you, but it's unclear that it solved OP's question. We're still waiting on a [mcve] so I can be sure the suggested solution works. Apparently OP abandoned the question so we'll probably never resolve it for certain.